specific OS-kernel tags or OS+kernel tags?
Is it interesting to use specific "OS-kernel' tags such as linux-kernel instead of linux kernel combination?
references: initial suggestion, then implementation

I could see someone wanting to follow Linux kernel (linux-kernel) related reverse engineering questions only, perhaps due to some particular interest in Linux rootkits. Unless there's a possibility of following a logical expression of tag combinations that I'm not aware of.
Reviewing "How do I correctly tag my questions?" I could see a case being made for having "linux" and "kernel" separate due to the terms being broader, or even skipping the kernel aspect completely. Using two tags actually flows better with the advice given in that meta since "kernel" would be the more generic term and "linux" would be the specific when you think about it. Perhaps the tag specificity should progress like: 

"rootkit" (Could be user mode or kernel mode) 
"kernel" (Ok, it's kernel mode, but for what OS)
"linux", (Ok, it's for Linux)

If we were to follow the StackOverflow way of doing it we would probably go with separate tags.


I know there's a 5 tags limit per question, yet I think such sub-tag
  are confusing because then, what does linux defines? usermode
  only?

Strictly speaking it means quite the opposite, since Linux in the strictest sense only refers to a kernel, not the userland. I'm sure RMS could give you an hour long talk about this, because he likes to emphasize the role that GNU userland tools play in the Linux world and not at last his own role in the GNU project (you should hear his argument about GNU/Linux vs. Linux). But then in everyday use "Linux" usually refers to the kernel along with the GNU userland packages and software even beyond that.
And I disagree that they are confusing. In fact it makes sense to make sure to distinguish for different kernels. Keep in mind how different the kernels of any BSD variant are compared to Linux or Windows (NT platform). There are certainly similarities, but also loads of differences. In most cases the rules are also fundamentally different in kernel and user land.
However, quite frankly I do not care so much whether it'll be kernel + linux or linux-kernel. But then you may be limited by the five tags per question rule as you point out in your question above.

I know there's a 5 tags limit per question, yet I think such sub-tag are confusing because then, what does linux defines? usermode only?
